# Nagios event handler script in bash to restart service, if its not started dont restart next one until condition is met

Tags: bash, event-handling, nagios

Hi Stackoverflow community,

i need a help with bash script since i am new to it. 
What i am trying to accomplish, we have a windows server, sometimes it hits 90% memory, so whenever nagios catches it, we want to restart these services via nrpe. But before restarting all of the services, first service has to come up and once its up continue with the next service restart.

Another option is to stop all 4 services and then start them sequentially.

Here is script that i wrote:

```
case "$1" in
OK)
;;
WARNING)
;;
UNKNOWN)
;;
CRITICAL) ## DECISION ENGINE RESTART
echo -n "Restarting Decision Engine_1"
cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/mail/DeServiceRestart.txt | mail -s "Restarting DE services" email@someteam.com -r Nagios@ATL-NM-01
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -p 5666 -c restart_service -a DecisionEngine_1;
if /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -t 30 -c check_service -a DecisionEngine_1 'crit=not state_is_ok()' > OK:
then
echo -n "Restarting Decision Engine_2"
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -p 5666 -c restart_service -a DecisionEngine_2
if /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -t 30 -c check_service -a DecisionEngine_2 'crit=not state_is_ok()' > OK:
then
echo -n "Restarting Decision Engine_3"
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -p 5666 -c restart_service -a DecisionEngine_3
if /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -t 30 -c check_service -a DecisionEngine_3 'crit=not state_is_ok()' > OK:
then
echo -n "Restarting Decision Engine_4"
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$2" -p 5666 -c restart_service -a DecisionEngine_4
else
   echo " Restart is complete"
fi
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Not sure where i made a mistake, would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear Igor, as I understand, you need to write event handler for nagios check. Before restarting all of the services, first service has to come up and once its up continue with the next service restart - you need to do some continuous loops with checks inside and sleeping between checks. Also you need to do some counters in loops which will be condition for loop-breakers if service startup hangs. Also pay attention to event handler timeout.

Comment: Hi Sasha, i am not sure why current script gives me errors, i have 0 experience with bash, it works without if statements, but sometimes it hands in infinit loop, restarting first services and doesnt restart the rest of the services...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments are in code. Double-check StopService function, because you not mentioned the way how to stop service, so I made it similarly.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICESTATE=$1;      #Common Check State (OK,WARNING,CRITICAL or UNKNOWN)
Host=$2;              #HostName or IP
SERVICESTATETYPE=$3;  #Hard or Soft service type

TimeOut=3;            #Time (seconds) to wait service start/stop 
                      #before next service processing
                      #You could not make infinite TimeOut, because 
                      #nagios process will kill this handler if it 
                      #will run too long


#Services is array with service names
Services=(DecisionEngine_1 DecisionEngine_2 DecisionEngine_3 DecisionEngine_4)

#add path to nagios plugins dir
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nagios/libexec

RestartService() {
   #function restarts services via NRPE.
   #Usage:  RestartService ServiceName
   echo -n " Restarting $1;"
   check_nrpe -H "${Host}" -p 5666 -c restart_service -a "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
   return $?
}

StopService() {
   #function stops services via NRPE.
   #Usage: StopService ServiceName
   echo -n " Stopping $1;"
   check_nrpe -H "${Host}" -p 5666 -c stop_service -a "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
   return $?
}

ServiceWait() {
   #function do continious checks service via NRPE, until success,
   #unsuccess check or TimeOut 
   #Usage:  ServiceWait ServiceName {start|stop}
   #start optin waits for success check
   #stop option waits for unsuccess check
   Logic="";
   [ "$2" == "start" ] && Logic="-eq"; #RC for start check should be 0
   [ "$2" == "stop" ] && Logic="-ne" ; #RC for stop check should NOT be 0
   [ -z "$Logic" ] && { echo "ServiceWait function usage error"; exit 19; }
   t=${TimeOut}
   while [ "$t" -ge 0 ]; do
      check_nrpe -H "${Host}" -p 5666 -t 30 \
                 -c check_service -a "$1" 'crit=not state_is_ok()' >/dev/null 2>&1
      RC=$?
      [ "$RC" $Logic 0 ] && { echo -n "CheckRC=$RC;"; return $RC; }      
                              #success check, no need to wait anymore
      let t--
      sleep 1
   done
   echo -n "TimeOut; " 
   return 3
}

#check if script received zero params in $1, $2 and $3
[ -z "${SERVICESTATE}" -o -z "${Host}" -o -z "${SERVICESTATETYPE}" ] && { 
    echo "Usage: $0 {OK|WARNING|UNKNOWN|CRITICAL} Hostname {SOFT|HARD}"; 
    exit 1; 
  }

case "${SERVICESTATE}" in
   OK)
   ;;
   WARNING)
   ;;
   UNKNOWN)
   ;;
   CRITICAL) ## DECISION ENGINE RESTART
     #uncomment if you need @mail
     #cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/mail/DeServiceRestart.txt | \
     # mail -s "Restarting DE services" email@someteam.com -r Nagios@ATL-NM-01
     RC=0

     if [ "$SERVICESTATETYPE" == "SOFT" ] ; then
        for (( i=0; i<${#Services[*]}; i++ )); do
           RestartService ${Services[$i]}
           ServiceWait ${Services[$i]} start
           RC=$?
           #if previous check failed, then do not try to do any restarts anymore
           [ "$RC" -ne 0 ] && break;         
           SuccessRestart+=(${Services[$i]})
        done
        echo "Restart is complete. ${SuccessRestart[*]} Return Code is ${RC}"
     elif [ "$SERVICESTATETYPE" == "HARD" ] ; then
        #Stop all services sequentially.
        for (( i=0; i<${#Services[*]}; i++ )); do
           StopService ${Services[$i]}
           #Here you need to experiment what to wait
           #May be it will be better to stay here for N seconds while
           #service is been stopped
           #rather then try to check service state
           ServiceWait ${Services[$i]} stop
           #sleep $TimeOut
        done
        #Start all services sequentially.
        for (( i=0; i<${#Services[*]}; i++ )); do
           RestartService ${Services[$i]}
           ServiceWait ${Services[$i]} start
           RC=$?
           #if previous check failed, then do not try to do any restarts anymore
           [ "$RC" -ne 0 ] && break;      
           SuccessRestart+=(${Services[$i]})
        done
     else
         echo "Unknown SERVICESTATETYPE $SERVICESTATETYPE option" 
         exit 20
     fi
   ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and looking it. Will try to implement it today/tomorrow and will come back with the result! Once again, thanks for your time and all these comments.

Comment: Hi Sasha, thank you, that worked but there is an issue on our side... Is there a way, to say stop all 4 services, once they are stopped - start from 1 to 4, but if for example 1 didn't start don't proceed with next one until first one is up? I would greatly appreciate if you could help with that.

Comment: Dear @IgorMatsenko, I added `SERVICESTATETYPE` option, you could get it from $SERVICESTATETYPE$ macros in nagios. See doc https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/macrolist.html#servicestatetype

Comment: Sasha, i greatly appreciate all the support and help! Will look into "SERVICESTATETYPE"! If anything, can i post question to the same thread? I've tried to message you but couldn't find an option to do so.